# Hyperlink inside a container div with z-index:-1 is not clickable

Tags: google-chrome, html, z-index

I have a container div with z-index of -1 (because above this container is a menubar with a menuitem with dropdown list). I have a hyperlink (a href text) inside this container. It is not getting clickable on Chrome. In IE, its Ok.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem myself. For anyone interested, what I did is I made the z-index of the menubar div +100 rather than making the z-index of the container div to -1. However, now, the opposite phenonmenon occurred i.e. worked in chrome but not in IE. Then, I found this site :

http://briancray.com/2009/04/16/target-ie6-and-ie7-with-only-1-extra-character-in-your-css/

which explains how to target the css explicitly for IE. So, with sort of binary switching the z-index for each browser type, I managed to do it.